# How can I run a function when any of the links in my 8x8 table are clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an 8x8 table of hrefs that are meant to be for a seat booking site (this is a uni assignment). When any of them are clicked, I want a javascript function to run. I get how to do this when you have a single link i.e. getElementById() and onclick but what I want is a way to apply the same function to all of the links without doing 64 unique ids and onclick lines... Surely this is a thing? Happy to clarify anything if what I've said doesn't make any sense and hoping I can get this sorted before the due date!

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to post what you've come up with so far.

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var links = document.getElementById("grid").getElementsByTagName("a");  //get every anchor tag in #grid div
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {     //loop through every anchor tag tag
        var link = links[i];
        link.onclick = function(e) {    //add an event handler to each anchor tag
            e.preventDefault();         //prevent the default action from happening, e.g. the href
            alert("Link clicked!");     //do whatever
        }
    }
```

Assuming that your hrefs are in a div called "grid", this will add an event handler to each of them doing whatever is within the `link.onclick = function(){` code

**http://jsfiddle.net/jofish999/v6kgsmqk/**

Comment: This is great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must to learn javascript. I explain you a little piece of code with jquery (you must to add jquery libraries to work).

### The HTML

We can add `data-*` custom attributes to identify X and Y axis.

```
   <div class="square" data-cell-x="0" data-cell-y="0"></div>
   <div class="square" data-cell-x="1" data-cell-y="0"></div>
   <div class="square" data-cell-x="2" data-cell-y="0"></div>
   <div class="square" data-cell-x="3" data-cell-y="0"></div>
   <div class="square" data-cell-x="4" data-cell-y="0"></div>
   <div class="square" data-cell-x="5" data-cell-y="0"></div>

   <div class="square" data-cell-x="0" data-cell-y="0"></div>
   <div class="square" data-cell-x="1" data-cell-y="1"></div>
   <div class="square" data-cell-x="2" data-cell-y="2"></div>
   <div class="square" data-cell-x="3" data-cell-y="3"></div>
   <div class="square" data-cell-x="4" data-cell-y="4"></div>
   <div class="square" data-cell-x="5" data-cell-y="5"></div>
```

### The Javascript

And now, with the help of jquery, we can add a few lines to handle onclick in all:

```
 $('.square').each(function() {
       // on each square we can:
      $(this).on('click' , function(e) {
          // prevent default action behaviour (i.e. a link)
          e.preventDefault();
          //catch dataset (data-* attributes)
          var ds = $(this).dataset();
          // alert with result
          alert("X: "+ ds.cellX+" ; Y: "+ds.cellY);
      });
 });
```

Good luck!

Comment: This could be easily achieved with plain javascript indeed

Comment: This is less code. Pure javascript is good, don't kill me !

Comment: OP was not asking [tag:jquery] thought

Comment: Yeah as part of the assignment, we're not allowed to use jquery, thanks though :)